# elasticsearch: search within text

Tags: elasticsearch

For example if name as P.Shanmukha Sharma and if user searches for Shanmukha will not be available for search result. its returning only for P.Shanmukha and Sharma, is there any way if i will search Shanmukha and it will return result?

```
"user" : {
        "properties" : {
          "city" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "created" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "latitude" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "longitude" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "profile_image" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "state" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "super_verification" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "username" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
```

username is defined as a search analyzer

and search query is

```
def EsSearch(self, index, page, size, searchTerm):
    body = {
        'query': {
            'match': searchTerm
        },
        'sort': {
                'created': {
                    'order': 'desc'
                }
        },
        'filter': {
                'term': {
                    'super_verification': 'verified'
                }
        }
    }
    res = self.conn.search(index=index, body=body)
    output = []
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        output.append(doc['_source'])
    return output
```

Comment: Which version of elasticSearch you are using ?

Comment: my version is 2.3.2

Comment: Please provide the search query which you are using

Comment: If you know the exact token everytime, then make a custom analyser to split at all non alpha characters. Or use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: @prasadkp updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so doing so much of research on ES i Got this solution with wildcard. Thanks EveryOne

```
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "username": {
          "value": "*Shanmukha*"
       }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, 2 way in to do so,

1. By GET method and URL:

   http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=username:*Shanmukha*&pretty=true
2. By Fuzzy Query
   as given by @krrish [this one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html):

Comment: but i need to search in whole index not for particular type. for fuzzy there is no curl . this query i am using  and getting an error like  [match] query does not support [users].
[body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [match] => Array
                        (
                            [fuzzy] => Array
                                (
                                    [users] => iva
                                )
                        )
                )

Comment: if i will go with get method and url how would be my search query..??